# How can I have an rcov task know if a subtask failed?

Tags: ruby, rake

I have this task:

```
task :all => ['foo', 'bar', 'announce_success']
```

If `foo` and `bar` don't raise exceptions, then `announce_success` happens. How can I have a particular task or code block execute if they *do* raise exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have defined your tasks will cause rake to exit as soon as one of the dependencies fails/raises and exception. This is the core functionality of rake.

One way to work around though is to do something like

```
task :all do
 task :tmp => ['foo','bar']
 begin 
   Rake::Task[:tmp].invoke
 rescue
  #do something with the exception
 end
end
```

Comment: pefect, thanks. i just put `Rake::Task[:foo].invoke`, `Rake::Task[:bar].invoke`, and `Rake::Task[:announce_success].invoke` right inside the begin block.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that goes against the grain of Rake.

Ruby has an `at_exit` hook you can add a block of code to, if you want to run a bit of cleanup when Rake terminates. You can combine rake-tasks and `at_exit` hook like this:

```
  task :cleanup do
    at_exit {
      # cleanup code here
    }
  end
```

Just make sure `:cleanup` is executed early in the list of dependencies.

Comment: cool… not sure I understand though -- how would this technique be used with my code above?